# How to check if one of URLSession tasks returned an error and if so to stop code execution?

Tags: swift, networking, uikit, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

I need to make 2 API calls simultaneously. I have 2 URLs for the calls, and if one of the calls will return any error I want to stop all the code execution.

How I tried to do it:

1. I have a function called `performRequest()` with a completion block. I call the function in my `ViewController` to update the UI - show an error/or a new data if all was successful. Inside it I create a `URLSession` tasks and then parse JSON:
2. I created an array with 2 urls:

   ```
   func performRequest(_ completion: @escaping (Int?) -> Void) {
    var urlArray = [URL]()

    guard let urlOne = URL(string: "https://api.exchangerate.host/latest?base=EUR&places=9&v=1") else { return }
    guard let urlTwo = URL(string: "https://api.exchangerate.host/2022-05-21?base=EUR&places=9") else { return }
    urlArray.append(urlOne)
    urlArray.append(urlTwo)
    }
   ```
3. Then for each of the url inside the array I create a session and a task:

   ```
    urlArray.forEach { url in
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .ephemeral)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in
            if error != nil {
                guard let error = error as NSError? else { return }
                completion(error.code)
                return
            }
            if let data = data {
                let printData = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                print(printData!)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.parseJSON(with: data)
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    print("all completed")
    completion(nil)
   }
   ```

For now I receive `print("all completed")` printed once in any situation: if both tasks were ok, if one of them was ok or none of them.

What I want is to show the `print` statement only if all tasks were completed successfully and to stop executing the code if one of them returned with error (for example if we will just delete one of the symbols in url string which will take it impossible to receive a `data`).

How can I do it correctly?

Comment: Can you use `URLRequest` instead of `URLSession` and work with async/await? However, it works from iOS 15, not compatible with earlier versions.

Comment: Hi, @HunterLion. Thank you for the reply! If it's work only from iOS 15 then no, unfortunately. I need to support from iOS 13

Comment: `async await` is available for iOS 13+ [Meet async await](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10132) show you how to implement the new api but also has samples on how it used to be done.

Comment: @loremipsum can you help me with some sample code with async/await and URLRequest for my case? I just stuck with it and can't go further...

Comment: The video has sample code. Give it a try and if you run into issues I can help. Just tag me. I am not going to write all the code for you.